# cannot connect to jmx jar process in docker container through jconsole

Tags: java, docker, jmx

I am trying to retrieve metrics from a java process that is running in a docker container. The process was started with the following command but trying to access it via jconsole as a test, results in 'connection failed' retry?

```
docker run -d --name=process-2-kafka --restart=always -p 22222:22222 -v 
/var/local/Blogs_Services/ProcessKafaka/:/program -w /program openjdk:8 
java
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=22222 - 
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false - 
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar testkafka.jar - 
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false – 
Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.www.xxx.yy – 
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=22222
```

I added the rmi.port and server.hostname after searching the internet but still results in the same error. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Are you able to telnet onto the port from inside and from outside your docker container?

Comment: The container is being run on someone else's machine. I will need to gain access to that machine in order to check. Gimme a minute. Thanks

Comment: I can telnet to the port outside the container but not sure how to do inside the container without disrupting his running process.

Answer (score 1):

JMX connections to containers are notoriously frustrating. Two things I would suggest to try:

1. Use a separate port for `jmxremote.port` and `jmxremote.rmi.port` (for example 22222 and 22223) and port forward both of these in docker
2. Set your `java.rmi.server.hostname` to be a name, eg `dockerhost`, and add `dockerhost` and the IP address of the machine hosting the container to your hosts file on all of the machine running the docker container, the docker container itself, and the machine you are running jconsole on. Then when you try to JMX, use `dockerhost` in the URL instead of an IP address.

These may not solve your problem, but fingers crossed, good luck!

Comment: so this did not work but thanks for the suggestion.